# Explain Phidgets temp. sensor sample python code

Tags: python, class

This is part of a sample Phidgets python code for a temperature sensor device. I started learning python recently and I need to write a python program for a Phidgets temperature sensor device using a Phidget InterfaceKit 8/8/8.

I understand, for example on the third line, that the object 'temperatureSensor' is going to the method 'setOnAttachHandler' (or a different method in the other lines) and uses the event 'TemperatureSensorAttached' (which is defined earlier in the program) as an argument for the parameter. However, does the program execute these things (line 4-6) right away or waits for an appropiate time?

Also, in line 7 what does 'as e' mean?

Please explain in very simple words because I'm very new to python and I learned the concept about objects and classes only a few days ago and i'm not that familiar with the lingo.

(PS. Pardon if i didn't use the correct terminology)

```
#Main Program Code
try:                                                                    
    temperatureSensor.setOnAttachHandler(TemperatureSensorAttached) 
    temperatureSensor.setOnDetachHandler(TemperatureSensorDetached)    
    temperatureSensor.setOnErrorhandler(TemperatureSensorError)
    temperatureSensor.setOnTemperatureChangeHandler(TemperatureSensorTemperatureChanged)
except PhidgetException as e:
    print("Phidget Exception %i: %s" % (e.code, e.details))
    print("Exiting....")
    exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`temperatureSensor.setOnAttachHanler` is called with the argument immediately when the interpretter reaches that line ... the function that is passed or event or whatever will not fire until a temperatureSensonsor hardware is attached...

`as e` makes the raised exception available as the local variable e

Comment: does this mean we can think of e as some sort of error structure?  That is, if all goes well, something is added to the "temperatureSensor" structure but something goes wrong, the something is added to the "e" structure?